# Is there a better word for "boss” in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is there a better word for *boss* in this sentence? as generally in production companies we call the person who is checking with circuit breaker failures with different name and not as boss.

> Take for example, a company suddenly had all of its electrical appliances switched off. When the boss looks at the circuit breaker, it seemed that nothing was wrong. he then went to call the technician who had arrived spontaneously.

The Dictionary Definition of *boss* is as follows. What are the other words that fits better than “boss“?

> a person who is in charge of a worker, group, or organization.
> "I asked my boss for a promotion"

The synonyms for boss are:

> head,
> head man/woman,
> top man/woman,
> chief,
> principal,
> director,
> president,
> executive,
> chief executive,
> chair,
> chairperson,
> chairman,
> chairwoman,
> manager,
> manageress,
> administrator,
> leader,
> superintendent,
> supervisor,
> foreman,
> forewoman,
> overseer,
> controller,
> employer,
> master,
> owner,
> proprietor,
> patron,
> boss man,
> number one,
> kingpin,
> top dog,
> bigwig,
> big cheese,
> Mister Big,
> skipper,
> gaffer,
> governor,
> guv'nor,
> honcho,
> head honcho,
> numero uno,
> padrone,
> sachem,
> big wheel.

Which best suits from *supervisor, foreman, owner* or any other from the list?

That is the sentence, I have. Role you can infer as the person written it did not mention.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124007/discussion-on-question-by-rachayita-is-there-a-better-word-for-boss-in-this-se).